# What is IPMI log directory?

Tags: ipmi

Does IPMI log have directory that all ipmi log messages are saved? I know how to view ipmi log by command like - ipmitool -I lanplus -H  -U root -P changeme chassis status. But I want to where this IPMI log is saved.

I search on internet and asked fellows. But I heard that IPMI log is not saved in any Linux directory. But I think it is not impossible, cause all unix system is saved as a file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does IPMI log have directory that all ipmi log messages are saved?

By default, no.  The IPMI event log is stored on the BMC (baseboard management controller) itself.  It will not send events to the OS of its own accord.

Take a look at the `ipmitool sel elist` command, it can be used to access the event logs on a case by case basis.

If you want to set up log collection from IPMI take a look at the `ipmievd` daemon, which is included with OpenIPMI tools. `ipmievd` can send the logs to `syslog`.

Comment: I already this command, but I want to know where this command result come from. I heard there is directory for this from my fellow. But still, I want to make sure.

Comment: It collects the information from the BMC itself. The logs are not stored at the operating system level unless you are using `ipmievd`, in which case they'll be sent to syslog.

Comment: Thank you Gene. Now I finally understand it. The information comes from the BMC itself not OS.